# How to complete level 10?

Tags: temple-run-2

I collected all masks, rings, chrstmas and vamentines day artefacts and reached level 10.
But no more objectives appear...
Do you know how to complete level 10 with more objectives ?

Comment: I'm at the same place. No answer to level 10 (objectives say "miser run desc" ) So keep collecting GEMs until the next upgrade! You are going to need those gems to get to that ever ellusive 150,000,000 score :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: with the series of updates up to and including January 2015, there are now enough objectives to make it to level 11.  There were a couple of objectives added in a December 2014 update:

- run 5 million meters, less onerous than the 10 million one
- unlock a hat
- run 2000 meters without coins

  and with the two in the latest update (1.12.2)
- run 50,000 meters as Scarlet Fox
- run 50,000 meters as Maria Selva

there were enough for me to complete level 11, which had some gem reward bonus.

Earlier answer, now no longer correct:

I don't believe there are enough tasks available to complete level 10.  Previously, there weren't enough tasks to complete levels 8 and 9, but eventually with various updates, new tasks were added and thus those levels eventually became complete able.  I expect it will be similar with level 10, so waiting for updates is the only solution I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently level 10, I've done every single mission and now I have only one to go: Infinirunner (10M meters run) and I'm quite far from that... But level 10 is for sure to make, you must simply do every objective you're asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Level 10 is the last level. There are in all 56 objectives in the game version 1.9. So if you have completed them all, then there is nothing left. For list of objectives check on this link:
http://templerun.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_Run_2